# Haskell selecting last items from the list of lists

Tags: list, haskell

Hi guys I have a little problem that I have been struggling with for a couple of hours, so I thought that maybe you could help me. I'd like to point out that I just started learning Haskell.

So I have a datatype called `Field` and a type called `Map` which is created from coordinates of field and type of this field

```
data Field = SM | S | M | W
type Map = (Int, Int, Field)
```

I also have a function that returns a list of lists of Maps, like this:

```
[[(1,1,W),(1,2,W),(1,3,W)],[(2,1,W),(2,2,SM),(2,3,W)],[(3,1,W),(3,2,W),(3,3,W)]]
```

Now here is the part where I'm stuck. I need to write a function that takes only the third variable of `Map` from that list and returns it as another list like this:

```
[[W,W,W],[W,SM,W],[W,W,W]]
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

This can actually be done easily with an anonymous function:

```
Prelude> data Field = SM | S | M | W deriving (Eq, Show)
Prelude> map (map $ \(_,_,field) -> field) [[(1,1,W),(1,2,W),(1,3,W)],[(2,1,W),(2,2,SM),(2,3,W)],[(3,1,W),(3,2,W),(3,3,W)]]
[[W,W,W],[W,SM,W],[W,W,W]]
```

However, the preferred way is to make `Map` a proper `data` type, not just a tuple redefinition.

```
data MapCell = MapCell {
        mapLocX, mapLocY :: Int
      , mapField :: Field
      } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

and then use `map (map mapField)`. Note that you won't be able to define your list quite the way you have it now... but there's a lot of redundant information in the anyway. Better build it like this:

```
type Chart = [[MapCell]]
yourMap :: Chart
yourMap = zipWith (\y fs -> zipWith (\x -> MapCell x y) [1..]) [1..]
   [ [W, W, W]
   , [W, SM,W]
   , [W, W, W] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, 3-tuples don't have a built in function to extract the nth value (like fst and snd for 2-tuples), so you will probably want to write one

```
third3 (_, _, x) = x
```

Once you have this, you just use `map` nested twice.

```
 map (map third3) theList
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in parts:

```
getThird (_,_, x) = x    
-- Using pattern matching to get the third element of Map
```

Combine this with `map` to transform the inner list of triples into list containing third elements:

```
getThirdElements = map getThird
```

Use the above function with `map` to get your desired answer

```
getListOfFields = map getThirdElements
```